# Why is a subnet range with a /24 netmask invalid for an AWS VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc

I'm currently attempting to establish a VPC in AWS using Terraform, and I'm dividing the CIDR range among my subnets as follows:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "dev_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/24"

  tags = {
    Name = "Dev environment VPC"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet_operational_db_dev_1" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.dev_vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.0.0/30"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"

  tags = {
    Name = "Public Subnet Operational db dev 1"
  }
}
```

I've calculated the CIDR range of my VPC to be from `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.0.255`.

Considering that the range of the subnet is from `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.0.3`, why is it invalid?

Comment: These docs indicate AWS uses 5 IPs per subnet. A /30 only provides 4, so maybe that's the limitation? https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/ " Amazon reserves the first four (4) IP addresses and the last one (1) IP address of every subnet for IP networking purposes. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest allowed CIDR block size for a VPC in AWS is a `/28` netmask, which equates to [16 IP addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-cidr-blocks.html).

Increase the number of IP addresses available to at least 16 in your subnet i.e. use a netmask of 28, or lower.

---

FYI, AWS also auto-reserves 5 IP addresses within each subnet.

As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/subnet-sizing.html):

> The first four IP addresses and the last IP address in each subnet CIDR block are not available for your use, and they cannot be assigned to a resource, such as an EC2 instance.

So even if a higher netmask was allowed, a subnet with CIDR block 10.0.0.0/30 would only provide 4/5 IP addresses reserved as a minimum by AWS themselves.